# Php ESP not running into php 5.3.4 version or later

Tags: php

I want to run [phpESP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpesp/) on my local pc. But I'm getting lots of errors. How can I run this without any error?. It shows me errors like this:

```
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\zrg\phpESP\admin\include\lib\espi18n.inc on line 66

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\zrg\phpESP\admin\include\lib\espi18n.inc on line 72

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\zrg\phpESP\admin\include\funcs.inc on line 23

Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_register() in C:\xampp\htdocs\zrg\phpESP\admin\manage.php on line 29
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you grab the latest copy of phpESP?  A version came out only a few months ago that must surely support a recent PHP.  Also you need to update your version of PHP, yours is pretty old.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpesp/

Comment: i am using php 5.4.1 version..
its still getting the error... and i have tried all version of phpESP